# "multiplication table" with custom function using python

Tags: python, matrix

I'm running a one-way ANOVA within 7 groups and would like to create a matrix containing Cohen's d for each couple of groups. To generalize the problem, it's creating a matrix based on one vector and using a custom function for the values. A similar example is a multiplication table, where the vector is range(1,11) and the function is multiplication. This is how it suppose to look:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. That's a nice table. You can get in Python if you want (I'd suggest using `numpy` and/or `pandas`). What have you tried? What problems have you run into?

Answer (score 0):

you mean something like this:

```
f = lambda x,y: x*y 
a = [1,2,3,4]
print([[f(x,y) for x in a] for y in a])
```

output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4],
 [2, 4, 6, 8], 
 [3, 6, 9, 12], 
 [4, 8, 12, 16]]
```